# Inserting value in middle of attribute table in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, point, attribute-table, editing

I using this attribute table of a point layer:

[image]

and i want to insert a new row between lines 7 and 8 when i start editing the layer, and not as The default- the new feature will be added automatically to the end of the attribute table. My goal is to join this attribute table with another attribute table from another layer.

How can i do it in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to do that?

Comment: i edit my question now.

Comment: How are you going to join both tables? Using the FID field is not a good idea since it's managed by Esri and can be modified when the data is modified. You'd better add a field with unique and stable values.

Comment: You can try adding a sort column, add the new record, manually (or with field calculator etc.) add desired order to sort column and then run sort tool using sort column.

Comment: yes this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly believe this is not possible, since you cannot change the FID field. Check the details on the ObjectID and FID in the link below. Maybe you have to redefine your problem and then try to find a better solution.

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010834